# How to use a service only to process and not store in the FeathersJS

Tags: feathersjs

How do I create a service that does only one processing, without registering in the database. An example: sending any data it does a processing using a hook and returns the result.

Here it works more the return is the answer of the data in the database, I do not care to store

```
app.use('/process', createService(options));
```

I tried something like this but got an error. Sorry, I am new to it.

```
app.use('/process', function(req, res) {

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in detail in the [Basics guide of the FeathersJS documentation](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/readme.html), specifically the [services section](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/services.html). The API documentation can be found [here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html). A service is any object or class that implements one or more of the following methods which can do pretty much anything:

```
class MyService {
  async find(params) {
    return [];
  }
  async get(id, params) {}
  async create(data, params) {}
  async update(id, data, params) {}
  async patch(id, data, params) {}
  async remove(id, params) {}
  setup(app, path) {}
}

app.use('/my-service', new MyService());
```

A custom service can be generated with the CLI via `feathers generate service` and choosing the "A custom service" option. It can then be edited in `src/services/<name>/<name>.class.js`.

Comment: As mentioned, you don't have to implement all the methods - we have a number of classes that only do `find` or `create` for example.